# How to create a selectable image in Mvc Asp.Net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view which displays a set of images. I want to be able to select an image and pass its Id back to the controller. How do I make the images selectable using jQuery? I am new to using the MVC framework.

Here is my view,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Select User</title>

@model xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.UserViewModel

</head>
<body>

<div class="divWrapper">
    <h1 align="center">Select a User</h1>

    <br />

    <div class="imageHolder">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Users.Length; i++)
        {
        <figure class="FigureAlign">
                <img class="imageBorder" src="@Url.Content(@System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imagePath"])" width="350" height="350" /> 
        </figure>
        }
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my UserViewModel,

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public User[] Users { get; }

    public UserViewModel(User[] users)
    {
        this.Users = users;
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; }
        public string Name { get; }
        public string ImagePath { get;}


        public User(int id,string name, string imagePath)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Name = name;
            this.ImagePath = imagePath;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use jquary to loop throw the selected items then ajax to send the selected data to backend

Comment: What do you mean _pass its Id back to the model_? What model? Do you mean you want to redirect to a server method (and pass the value of the associated `User.Id` to it)?

Comment: @Alen.Toma The images are currently not selectable. How do I select an image using jQuery?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry! I want to pass the id from view to the controller.

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: For jQuery image selection part, use something like `var selectedImage = $(this).attr("id")` or `var selectedImage = $(this).data('id')` on `click` event. Then pass the image ID by AJAX callback to action method in controller.

Comment: Are you wanting to redirect when you click on the image (in which case just wrap the `<img>` in a `<a>`, or do you want to make an ajax call (in which case add a `data-id="@Model.Users[i].Id"` attribute in the `<img>` and handle its click event and retrieve the value

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".imageContainer img").click(function(){
// here we bind the click event to the image
if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) 
 $(this).removeClass("selected"); // deselect the image 
 else $(this).addClass("selected"); // select the image
});

/// lets save the images and send its data to the backend
function Save(){
var selectedImages= []
$.each($(".imageContainer img"), function(){
if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) 
 selectedImages.push($(this).attr("objectId"));
});

/// now that we have the selected items we should send it to the backend using ajax
  $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(selectedImages),
                url: "/save",// this is a test , this method should have a List<int> parameter becouse selectedImages is List<int>
                success: function (data) {
                    // now reset the selected images
                    $(".imageContainer img").removeClass("selected");                   
                }
            });
  }


});
```

```css
img{
width: 100px;
height:100px;

}

.selected{
border:1px solid red;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="imageContainer">

<img objectId="1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" />
<img objectId="2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg" />


</div>
```